# Why switch case in javascript doesn't work with string on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have implemented javascript Switch case.This switch case works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge. What is the reason for this?

Edit: the labels var get the label elements of the checked check boxes.

Please review the below code .

```
    function getSelectedProducts() {
    var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("nf-checked-label");
    var selectedProducts = [false, false, false, false, false];
    for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        switch (labels[i].innerText) {
            case 'Risk':
                selectedProducts[0] = true;
                break;
            case 'Incident':
                selectedProducts[1] = true;
                break;
            case 'Audit':
                selectedProducts[2] = true;
                break;
            case 'Compliance':
                selectedProducts[3] = true;
                break;
            case 'Hazard':
                selectedProducts[4] = true;
                break;
            default:
                console.log("no case matched");
        }
    }
    return selectedProducts;
}
```

Comment: So what errors do you get?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `labels[i].innerText` returns the text with some spaces, hence why, say `"Risk "` doesn't match `"Risk"`

Comment: what happens when it works and what happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: works fine in all browsers ... switch is as old as javascript ... what is the **exact** value of `labels[i].innerText`

Comment: @CataJohn no erraor, But the returned array has all false values, every time.

Comment: As a side note - why not have `selectedProducts` as an object, so you can just say `selectedProducts["Risk"] = true`

Comment: Ok, so right before the `switch` statement, add a `console.log(labels[i].innerText);` and check the logs.

Comment: @vlaz I checked in developer tools, but the innerText gives string with no spaces at the ends.

Comment: @CataJohn if there is whitespace around it, that won't show it. Log the value + length of value or maybe log the value surrounded by some delimiters.

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `i`.

Comment: @HemalKithulagoda then either the value doesn't match for another reason or...you're wrong. It's not possible for equal values to not be...equal. The most common reason is because whitespace, because `innerText` will give you a *text* representation but not necessarily only the text present, especially if you have something like `<span>Text<span></span><span>` - i.e., some extra tags inside the one with the text.

Comment: Clearly, the value of `labels[i].innerText` doesn't match any of those `case` labels on Edge; it has whitespace, or zero-width space, or something that makes it not a match. So that's what you need to focus on. `switch` [is not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

Comment: Blind shot: Try with `textContent`. innerText may not return the whole text (along with forcing a reflow...)

Comment: My problem is it works perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox but why it is not working specifically in Edge.

Comment: @HemalKithulagoda - Because different browsers do different things with HTML markup, particularly around whitespace.

Comment: @Kaiido you mean `textContent` but yeah, I was going to suggest the same. `innerText` is non-standard and a Microsoft creation, to boot. I am not at all surprised it behaves differently on Microsoft browsers. EDIT: you corrected it before I commented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `innerText` property value being different in Chrome/Firefox to Edge. The Firefox/Chrome had the `innerText` with no white space at the ends. However the `innerText` property in Edge had whitespaces at the end. Therefore I used `labels[i].innerText.trim()` instead of `labels[i].innerText`.

Edit: I used `labels[i].textContent.trim()` as suggested by @Kaiido.

Comment: use `labels[i].textContent` instead, you'll have consistent behavior.

Comment: @Kaiido textContent also has white space at the ends. It still needs trim().

Comment: But it will be consistent across browsers and won't need for CSS to be recalculated at this time.

Comment: You had just post the JS function and here we need to assume for your HTML. You can try to provide a full sample code. so that we can directly make a test with it without assuming anything. It can help us to understand the issue in better way and we can try to provide you a helpful suggestion to solve the issue.